# Proper way to use JWT between ASP.NET Core 2 and Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, jwt

After about a week of reading tutorials, watching videos, and reading books, it seems more complicated than it should be to properly set up a JWT based authentication system between ASP.NET Core (and EF Core), with an Angular front end.

What is the recommended way of setting up this type of authentication system with these tools that allows the front end to get user data within any component after logging in?

Comment: which part of the process is the problem? did you get any part of it to work?

Comment: Actually yes. But one problem is that it seems that there are so many different ways of doing these. For example whether you are embracing reactive programming or not. I was not sure if there is a "right way" of doing this.

Comment: there is no single right way to do it. maybe you could elaborate more on your particular dilemmas and then we could focus on them in answers.